# Reset/remove all values in an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array_flipped array that looks something like:

```
{ "a" => 0, "b" => 1, "c" => 2 }
```

Is there a standard function that I can use so it looks like (where all the values are set to 0?):

```
{ "a" => 0, "b" => 0, "c" => 0 }
```

I tried using a foreach loop, but if I remember correctly from other programming languages, you shouldn't be able to change the value of an array via a foreach loop.

```
foreach( $poll_options as $k => $v )
  $v = 0; // doesn't seem to work...
```

**tl; dr:** how can I set all the values of an array to 0? Is there a standard function to do this?

Comment: Your `foreach` does not work because `$v` is a copy of the current value, not a reference to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `foreach` to reset the values;

```
foreach($poll_options as $k => $v) {
  $poll_options[$k] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 24):

```
$array = array_fill_keys(array_keys($array), 0);
```

or

```
array_walk($array, create_function('&$a', '$a = 0;'));
```

Answer (score 6):

`array_fill_keys` function is easiest one for me to clear the array. Just use like

```
array_fill_keys(array_keys($array), "")
```

or

```
array_fill_keys(array_keys($array), whatever you want to do)
```

`foreach` may cause to decrease your performance to be sure that which one is your actual need.

Answer (score 5):

Run your loop like this, it will work:

```
foreach( $poll_options as $k => $v )
    $poll_options[$k] = 0;
```

Moreover, ideally you should not be able to change the structure of the array while using `foreach`, but changing the values does no harm.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use an ampersand...

```
foreach( $poll_options as &$v)
  $v = 0;
```

Or just use a for loop.

Comment: That's not how you `foreach` by reference. The ampersand goes onto `$v` (and the key is redundant).

Answer (score 4):

As of PHP 5.3 you can use lambda functions, so here's a functional solution:

```
$array = array_map(function($v){ return 0; }, $array);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try this

```
foreach( $poll_options as $k => &$v )
    $v = 0;
```

Address of `$v`

Answer (score 2):

```
array_combine(array_keys($array), array_fill(0, count($array), 0))
```

Would be the least manual way of doing it.

Comment: array_fill() takes 3 params, the first one needs to be the starting index.  other than that, nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types for variable assignment in PHP,

1. Copy
2. Reference

In reference assignment, ( `$a = &$b` ), $a and $b both, refers to the same content. ( [**read manual**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php) )

So, if you want to change the array in thesame time as you doing `foreach` on it, there are two ways :

### 1-  Making a copy of array :

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
        $array[$key] = 0 ; // reassign the array's value
}
```

### 2 - By reference:

```
foreach($array as $key => &$value){
        $value = 0 ;
}
```